# Can't figure out why I keep getting a "list index out of range" error. Can someone assist me?

Tags: python

I keep getting a "list index out of range" error, but don't know why. Can someone help?

```
arr = []
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    z = int(input())
    n = int(input())
for x in range (x+1):
    for y in range(y+1): 
        for z in range(z+1): 
            arr.append([x,y,z])
for i in range(len(arr)): 
    if (arr[i][0] + arr[i][1] + arr[i][2] == n): 
        del arr[i]
print(arr)
```

Comment: Did you mean to have only part of your code under the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block?

Comment: Generally speaking, deleting items of the array you are iterating over with range is a bad idea: the range parameter is evaluated at the beginning, but the list gets shorter inside the loop.

Comment: Modifying a list while you're iterating over it is usually a bad idea.  In this particular case, the list gets shorter partway through your loop, but your loop is going to try to iterate over the original list, so it's going to run off the end.

Comment: Adding to what was said above, another practice to avoid is naming your iterator variables (in this case, the `x`, `y`, `z` of `for x in...` etc. with name of the variable which you are constructing the range.

Comment: Also, note that using the same variable as index and as a bound, as in `for x in range(x+1)` doesn't help readability, and can lead to some bugs - any upper bound other than `y+1` or `z+1` would have caused bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're mutating your list as you traverse through it. In your specific example, you would actually be better off creating a new list from the old list. In this example:

```
arr = [x for x in arr if (x[0] + x[1] + x[2] != n)]
```

EDIT: In addition to the comment about the scope of this activity relative to main.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to build a list like this as a comprehension, where you can filter the elements as you build the list rather than having to go back and try to extract them after the fact:

```
x, y, z, n = (int(input()) for _ in range(4))
arr = [
    [i, j, k] 
    for i in range(x+1) 
    for j in range(y+1) 
    for k in range(z+1) 
    if i + j + k != n
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you iterate over the len of an array, but that len is computed and stored at the beginning, it isn't update. Let's say the array if of len 5, the loop generates `0,1,2,3,4` but if you delete an item during the loop, when doing `arr[4]` it'll fail

---

The best solution is to **keep** interesting items, not delete the others, whether with another array, or a list comprehension. Also you can iterate of the values of an array, not on indices

```
# new array
new_vals = []
for v in arr: 
    if sum(v) != n: 
        new_vals.append(v)

# list comprehension
arr = [v for v in arr if sum(v) != n]
```